# How to log a Python crash?

Tags: python

I am running a python code in a raspberry Pi. The code is supposed to last forever. However, after a few hours it crashes. Since it is running on a remote machine, I cannot see the message it gives during the crash.

How can I store this message on a file so I can see what was the problem? is this does autonomously in linux? or should I write some function to export the error during crash. How can I do that?

Comment: How are you launching your Python program exactly?

Comment: "Since it is running on a remote machine, I cannot see the message it gives during the crash." That really shouldn't be a restriction.

Comment: i ssh the raspberrypi and run the python code : sudo python file.py

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can store the output in a file, if the process is started like this:

```
python script.py >> /logdir/script.py.log 2>&1
```

Comment: is it possible to view the log on the terminal and log it on script.py.log at the same time?

Comment: @alandalusi use ``tail -f /logdir/script.py.log`` to watch the log.

Comment: It is funny that unlike running the script on terminal, the results are not put on the log file on real-time. any reason for this?

Comment: This is probably because of tail's sleep interval. You can set that like this: "tail -s 0.1 -f /logdir/script.py.log"

Comment: Its probably because of the buffering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering need to test this solution though

Answer (score 11):

You can have a main function and log in case if main function crashes

```
def main():
   ...
   raise ValueError("Crashed because I'm a bad exception")
   ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
   try:
      main()
   except Exception as e:
      logger.exception("main crashed. Error: %s", e)
```

This is better in case if you're using something like logstash and want to see the error and the time on your UI.

Thanks to [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric) for improving the answer

Comment: Use `logger.exception('main crashed')`, which will print the stack trace too

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to include logger.exception

Comment: Make sure, to setup the logging at some point. Python 3.9: `logger.basicConfig(filename=..., encoding='utf-8', level=logger.DEBUG)`. Also the library is called `logging`, not `logger`. (So for the upper code, you would need `import logging as logger`.)

Comment: 3.8 without parameter encoding, so `logger.basicConfig(filename=..., level=logger.DEBUG)`. See [Python docs for details (in your language :)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had tried many attempts myself, but they all seemed weird...Until I figured it out!
Simply write this code around your python file, and all should be well!
By the way, I will be naming the crashlogs CRASH- and then the python time (e.g. CRASH-1607012036.015824.txt)

```
try:
    <your program here>
except Exception as e:
    crash=["Error on line {}".format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno),"\n",e]
    print(crash)
    timeX=str(time.time())
    with open("monstergame/crashlogs/CRASH-"+timeX+".txt","w") as crashLog:
        for i in crash:
            i=str(i)
            crashLog.write(i)
```

Note: This is Python 3 code, not Python 2